# How do I remove a particular level occurring in all factors in a dataframe

Tags: r

After reading in data and cleaning it, I ended up with factor columns that have levels that should no longer be there.

For example, d below has one blank cell in excel. When it’s read in, the factor columns have a level "", which shouldn’t be part of the data.

```
d <- read.csv(header = TRUE, text='
x,y,value
a,one,1
,,5
b,two,4
c,three,10
')

d
#>   x     y value
#> 1 a   one     1
#> 2             5
#> 3 b   two     4
#> 4 c three    10

str(d)
#> 'data.frame':    4 obs. of  3 variables:
#>  $ x    : Factor w/ 4 levels "","a","b","c": 2 1 3 4
#>  $ y    : Factor w/ 4 levels "","one","three",..: 2 1 4 3
#>  $ value: int  1 5 4 10
```

How do I remove this level, "" from the factors which are about 20 factors in the data frame, without deleting the entire row that has just one empty cell, cause this will reduce my sample size from 299000 to just 7 observation(which I have tried before).

Comment: You already have a `''` cell.  So, what should replace the blank elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to replace the `''` with `NA` and use `droplevels` to remove the unused levels

```
d[1:2] <- lapply(d[1:2], function(x) droplevels(replace(x, x=="", NA)))
levels(d$x)
#[1] "a" "b" "c"
levels(d$y)
#[1] "one"   "three" "two"
```

---

Another option while reading the dataset (as we assume the OP wanted `factor` columns would be

```
d <- read.csv("yourfile.csv", na.strings = "")
```

This should make sure that the `''` will be read as NA.

#### Update

Suppose, there are numeric columns in between and we need to do the `replace`/`droplevels` only for the `factor` columns

```
 d[] <- lapply(d, function(x) if(is.factor(x)) droplevels(replace(x, x== "", NA))
              else x)
```

Comment: @ZheyuanLi It is possible. The `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` will make it a character column, but the `''` will remain as such (in the present example, it didn't change to NA )

Comment: this stringsAsFactors = FALSE changes all factors to character@Zheyuan. I have 22 columns so I did d[1:22], but I get this error message:  Error in UseMethod("droplevels") : 
  no applicable method for 'droplevels' applied to an object of class "c('integer', 'numeric')"

Comment: @MrB  In the example you have the first two columns as factors.  If you have numeric columns in between, subset only those factor columns i.e. or use `if/else` i.e. `d[] <- lapply(d, function(x) if(is.factor(x))  droplevels(replace(x, x=="", NA)) else x)`

Comment: wow it worked@akrun thank you much. but I have a small ish. Among the 22 factors I have numeric variables in between. How do I apply the function to other factor while skipping the numeric column so as not get the error message. Thank you.

Comment: WOW it worked perfectly, I can't believe this I have been online for two days to solve this ish. Just register on this forum today to try it out. You are a life saver @ akrun.

Comment: Please is there a way to remove the NAs WITHOUT deleting the entire row or column?? so that my sample size will not drastically reduce. Since the function turns the empty cells to NA I need to remove them so I can perform numercal analysis

Comment: @MrB Did you meant to remove a entire row if there is any NA in a row?  If that is the case `d[!rowSums(is.na(d)),]` or to remove  columns `d[!colSums(is.na(d))]`

Comment: No please, just the NAs, and not the entire row or column cause this will reduce my observation to just two. Thank you @akrun

Comment: @MrB  One way would be to remove the NA and place it in a `list` as list can have unequal length but data.frame can hold only columns with equal length. i.e. `lapply(d, na.omit)`  It depends upon what you really wanted to do.

Comment: Thank you, sorry the help is getting a bit longer, it did work. But please, is there any consequences of changing from data frame to list, I am a beginner.

Comment: @MrB  If you remove the NAs, the corresponding elements will change .i.e removing a NA means the next non NA element will occupy its place.  It all depends  on what you finally want to do.

Comment: Say you have a survey with levels "no", "no opinion", "yes" and you'd like to drop "no opinion", and say if there are questions where the only answers are "no" and "no opinion", wouldn't ``droplevels`` drop "yes" as a level as well, because it does not occur in some questions (undesirable side-effect), rather than keeping it as an unused level (desired). In other words, doesn't this approach drop too many levels? In other words, this method removes "a particular level" (OPs request) as well as all unused levels (side-effect).

Comment: @PatrickT  It does drop that.  If you need to use only specific levels, then you may need to apply `factor` with `levels` specified

Comment: Thanks akrun. I'll see if I can work something out for my use case, if not I'll post a question. :-)